# Should Indexing supply Direct Access to pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which have several columns. I want to extract rows by combination of values from two specific columns, so I use the `set_index()` property to index the dataframe by those columns. I figured that after doing so, I will have a direct access (O(1)) to rows for a given combination of keys. Currently, It does not seem like the case, It takes quite some time for a `df.ix[ix1,ix2]` operation to take place.

Example:

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
In [228]:    df
Out[228]:
             ID1             ID2        score
752476   5626887150_0    5626887150_6    96
752477   5626887150_0    5626887150_7    95
752478   5626887150_0    5626887150_2    95
752479   5626887150_0    5626887150_8    93
752480   5626887150_0    5626887150_1    89
752481   5626887150_0    2142280814_5    88
752482   5626887150_0    5626887150_3    84
752483   5626887150_0    6625625104_5    82
752484   5626887150_0    2142280814_4    81
```

And say I want to look at the score column in different ID1,ID2 combinations. To easily do this, i'm setting ID1 and ID2 as indexes and obtain the following result:

```
In [230]: df = df.set_index(['ID1','ID2']) 
Out[230]:
                               score
ID1                 ID2 
5626887150_0    5626887150_6     96
5626887150_7                     95
5626887150_2                     95
5626887150_8                     93
5626887150_1                     89
2142280814_5                     88
5626887150_3                     84
6625625104_5                     82
2142280814_4                     81
```

Now I can easy access my data with ID1,ID2 combinations (e.g. `df.ix['5626887150_0','5626887150_6']`), that's true. BUT, it does not seem to be an O(1) access. It seems to take quite some time to return a value on a large dataframe.

So what exactly is the `set_index()` method doing? and is there a way to force an O(1) acess to the data?

Comment: Why don't you use pandas multi-axis indexing with .loc, .iloc and .ix? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html. I'm not 100% sure, but I think it works in O(1)

Comment: I think I did use it... I guess I should give an example.

Comment: specify you labels as a tuple, e.g.``('5626887150_0','5626887150_6')``, right now it tries first to find it in each axis

Comment: @Jeff actually, I've checked both ways on 1000/1000000 rows dataframe, and both looks like O(1) operations

Comment: pls make sure that your multi-index is sorted, e.g. what is ``df.index.lexsort_depth``. It will still work if its not; it should be 1. try ``df.sortlevel(inplace=True)`` at which point should be much faster. Indexing with multi-index will be MUCH faster when sorted.